# Split() function in python

Tags: python, split

In the second line of the following code the string will be split into 2 parts and returned as list elements.

```py
mystring = "Hello everyone! welcome to the world of python"
print(mystring.split("!"))
```

How do I directly access these list elements without assigning returned list into another variable?

Comment: It is a list so you can  use  `mystring.split("!")[0]` and `mystring.split("!")[1]`

Comment: Why don't you want to assign it to a variable?  If you really don't want to use a variable, you can just do `mystring.split("!")[0]`.

Comment: Assigning the output of `split` to a variable will always be better than splitting two times the same string...

Answer (score 1):

Since split returns an array you can directly access it like an array mystring.split("!")[0] for first element and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want `mystring.split("!")[0]` and `mystring.split("!")[1]`, though I do wonder why you don't want to use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring = "Hello everyone! welcome to the world of python"

print(mystring.split("! ")[0]) #Hello everyone
mystring.split("! ")[1] #welcome to the world of python
```

if you want a list of words of each sentence:

```
mystring = "Hello everyone! welcome to the world of python"

mystring1 = mystring.split("! ")[0].split(" ")
mystring2 = mystring.split("! ")[0].split(" ")
print(mystring1, mystring2)
```

```
['Hello', 'everyone'] ['welcome', 'to', 'the', 'world', 'of', 'python']
```

Answer (score 0):

When running the following code:

```
phrase = "Hello!Friend"

x = phrase.split("!")

print(x)
print(x[0])
print(x[1])
```

This is the output:

```
['Hello', 'Friend']
Hello
Friend
```

x is an array

x[0] contains "Hello"

x[1] contains "Friend"